# FlatPack in Ubuntu Core

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, flatpak

Ubuntu Core has multiple useful features for iot but snap is not one of them because of proprietary store/no self-hosted repositories option.

Is there any way to use flatpack in Ubuntu Core / a real open source package distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not currently possible to use Flatpak on Ubuntu Core, as far as I'm aware. Someone would have to [snap Flatpak](https://snapcraft.io/first-snap/c) to get Flatpaks working on Ubuntu Core. 
[It's not even possible to use Debs on Ubuntu Core](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/packages), according to the Ubuntu website.

Also, 'Ubuntu Core has multiple useful features for iot', what features does it have that you'd find useful that doesn't use snappy? The whole of Ubuntu Core is snap!

Keep an eye on [this snapcraft forum post](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/flatpak-on-ubuntu-core/10194) for more!

Comment: Lack of private repositories. Doesn't make sense to upload private packages to ubuntu store for local use. They shouldn't leave local network.

Comment: @FrakyDale Please can you explain that [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/flatpak-on-ubuntu-core/10194/)? :) You probably need to get in touch with Canonical directly to ask about what you want to do, Zyga has offered to do that for questioner53 on the forum and I'm sure he'd do the same for you if you asked, just leave a post on the topic that I linked! :)